# CVS change revision of file to a newer one

Tags: version-control, cvs, revision

simple question. I got a file xy.c that has a repository revision 1.1. Its on a branch. In head there is a newer version with version 1.4 . Now i want the file xy.c point to version 1.4.

**I already tried cvs update -A xy.c**
and it updates the file and cvs status show revision 1.4 but i cant commit that file and when I check it out its still revision 1.1 .
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think my answer is the right one. If it works, can you accept it. Stack Overflow is gamified and answerers like to get the points if their answers are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to somewhat bypass CVS and send the file to stdout (`-p`) and then back into the file.

```
cvs update -r 1.4 -p xy.c > xy.c
```

I know that sounds crazy or like overkill, but some seemingly-simple things are difficult in CVS.

(Note that if this file has+needs an execute bit set this will be lost and you'll need to `chmod +x xy.c`. Probably not necessary if `.c` is indeed the extension, but if it's something else you might need it.)